# Shoe not moving properly with rig

Tags: rigging, parent, rigify

When i move the right foot bone(duplicate shoe) it warps and also moves and warps the left shoe(original). And when i move the other foot it does the same vice versa. Im also not sure how to move the rest of the leg bones with the foot.[image]

Ive parented the shoes several way, clearing parents in between times. ive joined things. ive used every weight technique when paring(even self painting). ive done everything that google, stackexchange, and youtube has to offer and i still cant seem to figure out why my feet/shoes done move with the rigify rig properly. ANY help would be great.. oh and i also did the data transfer modifier at a point, and i have armature modifier on both feet and have already applied the scales of each foot. i thought it was a origin issue so i cycled through them all and i still cant figure it out. I will gladly add the .blend file if someone tells me how. Thanks in advanced

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can simply use any cloudservice like oneDrive or dropbox....

Comment: sorry i took 2 days to reply. uploading the link to the file right now

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SiKmeXGrw5BJ5wxNOtxhbzmG0bTGRx5x/view?usp=sharing                 <<The .blend file